# Changing Zurb Foundation grid columns so padding is only on one side

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, grid-layout

Does anyone know if there is a setting to put the **column-gutter** to only one side? Currently it adds half to each side of the column, so for instance if you wanted a 14px column gutter, it would add 7px on each side. This causes the first column in a row to have a 7px indentation.

I could hack it with extra CSS, but I would prefer to change it in default settings if I can.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible as far as I know without creating your own mixin or modifying the existing grid-column mixin, and that's not something you'd want to do for a simple case like that.

I'd suggest to instead create your own class for this, for example:

**SASS**

```
.left-collapse {
  .columns {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: $column-gutter;
  }
}
```

And then just add the class to your parent row, almost like you'd want to do with a collapse class for removing all gutter widths - so you'r row would then look like this:

```
<div class="row left-collapse">
   <div class="large-4 columns">FOO</div>
   <div class="large-4 columns">FOO</div>
   <div class="large-4 columns">FOO</div>
</div>
```

If you'r not using SASS then just add in your $column-gutter size (default in v4: 1.875em) in the padding-right in your CSS file.

Comment: Thanks am_, that makes very good sense. I'll make use of the collapse class for sure. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

For an even gutter on each side you can hard code it:

```
.collapse-half {
  .columns {
    padding-left: .46875rem;
    padding-right: .46875rem;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed on the Foundation Docs 6 site, they include a `.row .row` class. This adds negative margins to the block grid example:

```
.row .row {
  margin-left: -0.9375rem;
  margin-right: -0.9375rem;
}
```

One solution would be to follow the pattern established in the `.row row` selector and add

```
.left-collapse {
  .margin-left: -$column-gutter;
}
```